# How to access property with odd characters like "#name"?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to display JSON result in HTML table using plain JavaScript without using JQuery or any other libraries, I have JSON response like below:

```
{
  "topalbums": {
    "album": [
      {
        "name": "Konvicted",
        "playcount": "61503",
        "mbid": "13141107-58e2-4984-bb90-55aa59fc03f6",
        "url": "http://www.last.fm/music/Akon/Konvicted",
        "artist": {
          "name": "Akon",
          "mbid": "1138a764-2212-4d0a-b02d-0dc14df91e08",
          "url": "http://www.last.fm/music/Akon"
        },
        "image": [
          {
            "#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/55550849.png",
            "size": "small"
          },
          {
            "#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/55550849.png",
            "size": "medium"
          },
          {
            "#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/55550849.png",
            "size": "large"
          },
          {
            "#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/55550849.png",
            "size": "extralarge"
          }
        ],
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "1"
        }
      },
```

I want to access the first image URL as seen above, I tried using it like below but did not worked:

```
var text;
for (i = 0; i < json.topalbums.album.length; i++) 
{
  text += json.topalbums.album[i].name + " "+json.topalbums.album[i].image[1].#text+"<br>";
}
```

Can anyone suggest some solution?.

Comment: `#` is not part of a variable name.  Try `['#text']` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `["#text"]` to access it:

```
var text;
for (i = 0; i < json.topalbums.album.length; i++) 
{
  text += json.topalbums.album[i].name + " "+json.topalbums.album[i].image[1]["#text"]+"<br>";
}
```